# How can I get around strict MIME checking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I'm getting this weird error in my console that is not allowing my CSS file to work.

5e23e4d738f55c71e4e9f547:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I have no idea what this means and I can't get any styles to apply.  I've linked my stylesheets the way I always have:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
```

Comment: Your web server is serving up CSS files with the wrong MIME type.

Comment: The preferable solution here is not to get around strict MIME checking, but to fix whatever is causing the files to be served with the wrong MIME type. Please tell us more about what kind of web server setup you are using.

Comment: I'm using Chrome - does that help?  Still pretty new to development so I'm not totally sure what you mean.

Comment: Chrome? As a server? I assume you're running some kind of plug in? Normally Chrome is just a browser.

Comment: Oh sorry!  I'm using node.js.

Comment: That smells good the *404* or similar error page. Check the Network panel of your dev-tools.

Comment: Are you sure that your node web-server is correctly serving files from the path you have above statically? Since Node doesn't do that out of the box like some other web servers.

Comment: I'd suggest you show us the server-side code that serves your `/stylesheets/main.css` code so we can offer some ideas on why it's not setting the proper mime type.  This is something you fix on the server.

Comment: Can you simply go to [that page](http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/main.css) and see if it's indeed your stylesheet that gets served?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the browser can not find the css file on the path that you specified.

Please make sure that your file main.css exists on the path you specified

Also make sure that you have set your assets folder as static so it can be accessed globally

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')); 
// If your resources are inside public folder inside root & /stylesheets/main.css is inside the public folder
```

To check if path is correct or not, just check this url in your browser & see if you are getting css file there or not